# Do "x" based on GPS location or manual address (android /iDevice)

Tags: android, iphone, gps

So I know next to nothing about GPS and Apps, but I do want to get my feet wet and have a (simple-ish in my mind) idea for a simple app based on GPS or manual address.

I basically need to know if you can do something like this

```
if GPS Location is (11.111/22.222) { Show(**THIS STUFF**) }
or if manual address is (555 Main St, Salem, OR) { Show(**THIS STUFF**)}
```

in android or iphone

Comment: you should try OnX on google play you can write a script to exactly do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can.  It's considerably more complex than that.  And there are apps for both platforms that do exactly that.  A quick search of Google, Apple Store, and Android Market will tell you what the current apps for that are.

If you want to do this yourself you will need to learn some new concepts.  Geofencing (geographic buffers). Geolocation (address to coordinate conversion).  And read up on how to efficiently use the location services provided by the devices you are writing for.

Comment: I do want to do it myself - and I was unaware of Geofencing. Thanks for some starting points in some research!

Comment: Absolutely.  When you have done some research and have more specific questions about how to implement these concepts on a particular platform be sure to ask them.  StackOverflow has a lot of knowledge in these areas kickin around.

Answer (score 1):

You should use android location api for GPS Location, and check in the onLocationChanged() method : if(myLocation.getLatitude==11.111 && mylocation.getLongitude==22.222)

On manual adress You should use android maps api.

Comment: You will (statistically) never be able to get your device to spit out a perfect coordinate to match against.  You will need some kind of geofencing.